# Promise.all() with map() returns undefined items in array

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Trying to generate an array of random numbers:

```
const arr = await generateValues(20, 500);

async function generateValues(numOfValues, max){
  return await Promise.all(
    new Array(numOfValues).map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random() * max))
  );
}
```

`const arr` is returning an array of length 20 but are all `undefined`.

Comment: You can only use await inside of an async function your code returns this error:
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` ignores empty elements in the array, so you have to use `fill` first.

```
var arr = new Array( 20 ).fill( 0 ).map( () => { ... } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not aware of `map`, it does not work with the blank or empty array. you have to use `fill` to insert at least one element.

try it.

```
async function generateValues(numOfValues, max){
  return await Promise.all(
    new Array(numOfValues).fill(0).map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random() * max))
  );
}
const arr = await generateValues(20, 500);
```